# set field to hidden if respective link is not clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I load additional info when a user clicks a link and there is a multi-select drop-down `holds[]` that appears.

If the user does not select the "more" info link, then the `holds[]` drop-down does not render, and does not show up in the post data `print_r($_POST);`

For the ajax, on success (the user clicks the more info link), it displays a chunk of html, which contains that `holds[]` drop-down (as seen in screenshot below).

Is it possible to add to the ajax/jQuery to set the `holds[]` drop-down as a hidden field if the respective "more" info link has not been clicked?

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using `datatables`. Am I correct?

Comment: no, just a regular table, with tr inserted after the "more" link that is clicked.

Comment: by 'a hidden field' do you mean an <input type="hidden" />? And are you talking about just the holds information, or all the info in that revealable drop down?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="hidden" /> <!--Will be hidden by defaul -->


.hidden {
    display:none;
}


$('.more').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown').toggleClass('hidden'); 
    //You haven't posted your html so I'm going to make some assumptions
});
```

Comment: I need to make it a hidden field. <input type="hidden" name="holds[]" />

Comment: @Brad: Why is it `type="hidden`? You mean just visually hidden right?

Comment: If the user does not click the "more" info link, its respectful holds[] field does not render in the html, so it basically never exists. I want it to render in some form (whether the user clicked the more info link or not)

Answer (score 0):

You could have the `more` button call a javascript function which does an ajax call which returns the data you're looking for and inserts it to the table after the row in which it was clicked:

```
$(".more").on('click', function() {
    var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post("process.php", {
            id: rowId
        }, function (data) {
            $(this).parent().parent().after(data);
            $(this).html("<a href='#' class='close' id='" + $(this).attr('id') + "'>close</a>");
        }
});

$(this).parent() // <td> containing "more"
    .parent() // <tr> containing <td> containing "more"
```

Comment: yes, I already have that. That works fine. It just doesn't render the holds[] field if the user does not select the respective "more" link. I want it to recognize the holds field on post, whether the user clicked the respective "more" link or not.

Comment: @Brad if you `.remove()` that data it'll never `POST`. I would recommend inserting it into your table with a `hidden` style, then simply toggle the visibility with the 'more'/'close' links. This way, you don't have to worry about hidden `input`s.